# jquery index of an element in an selector array

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector

I'm trying to get the index of an element within an array returned by a jquery selector.

Here's my code:

```
$("div").click( function(){
  alert( $.inArray( $(this), $("#div") ) );
});
```

An an example, for this HTML:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
```

I want it to display "4" when the user clicks the div containing D.  Is there any way to do this?  This inArray function doesn't seem to do what I expect when applied to selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want:

```
$("div").click(function(){
  alert($(this).index("div"));
});
```

(You would need to add 1 to the result of the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) call since the index is 0-based).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/tdcVU/

Answer (score 0):

Another method you could use is the [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
alert($(this).prevAll("div").length + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

.index()

var selectedItem = $(this);
var index = $('div').index(selectedItem);

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update of your code that would work -

```
$("div").click( function(){
  alert( $.inArray( this, $("div") ) );
});
```

The changes are -

- Changed the selector passed into the array argument of `inArray` from `#div` to `div`
- Passed a normal JavaScript DOM element rather than a jQuery wrapped
  element into the `inArray` function

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/CfY8j/